# Android process layout

Tags: android, memory-management, java-native-interface, jit, unsafe

I came across [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/verifying-apps-art#Stack_Size) site and also there are some discussions about the topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24885561/unified-stack-for-native-and-java-in-android-runtime-art) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35542630/android-java-stack-vs-native-stack) but I still could not find the answer.

It has been stated that Dalvik had separate stacks for native and Java code, while ART has a unified stack for the native and Java code. I tried to verify this by extracting memory addresses in an Android app (using unsafe lib). However, it seems that they belong to different memory regions ( it looks that the native heap resides between the native stack and the Java stack). So what is meant by a unified stack? is that at low level, or may be this is at an abstract level?